# Symfony 4.4 dump is not outputing anything when response is returned

Tags: symfony, dump

I wanted to make use of the symfony function `dump()` and have to determine that there is no output soon as I return a response. I have made a very simple controller to proof that like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class EasyController extends AbstractController
{
    public function number()
    {
        $number = random_int(0, 100);
        dump($this);
        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
            );
    }
}
```

If I include an "exit" after the dump (), the dump is shown in the browser, if I return the response, I only see the dump in the Symfony Profiler (but not always). But it works with this simple example.

Why is this?

I can output a "`var_dump()`" from inside a controller, a `dump()` from a twig template, but the output of the `dump()` from the controller disappears when I return a response.

I would really love to see my dump and my output in the browser.

Comment: There is `dd()` since symfony 4.1 which is simply `dump() and die()` in one handy function.

Comment: > Why is this ?

Because Fabien, Nicolas and other symfony core developers are **very smart** people :)

Answer (score 3):

Symfony has a handy function:

```php
dd($data); // is an equivalent of dump($data); die();
```

---

> but the output of the dump() from the controller disappears when I return a response.

It doesn't disappear. Symfony puts it to a profiler (aka debug-bar)
Symfony tries to 'inject' debug-bar to each response with `Content-Type: text/html` and at least `<body>` in it.

So if you do this:

```php
$data = ['hello' => 'world'];
dump($data);
// since 'body' is there, symfony will try to inject 
return new Response('<body></body>');
```

you'll see it in debug-bar

[image]

But if you send an 'empty' response → you'll see nothing

```php
$data = ['question' => 'Where\'s the profiler, Lebowski?'];
dump($data);
// there will be no debug-bar 
return new Response('');
```

But just because you don't see it doesn't mean there isn't one. You can always visit `/_profiler` URL to find last requests and their profiler data.

---

> Why is this?

Outputting 'pretty' debug-data, means 'injecting' some HTML (+ JS).
This will **probably break** your layout, that's' way symfony "moves it away"

Yes, if you do `dd($data);` and then view the source, you'll notice some `<script>` and `<span class=sf-dump-note>`

Therefore, there are **several ways** to output debug-dump from twig.
Destructive and nondestructive:

**Destructive** with twigs built-in function `dump()`

```
<body>
{{ dump('your data', ['hello', 'world']) }}
</body>
```

Which will generate and output at the spot you've called it. Yes, it will inject its HTML (+JS)

**Nondestructive** with `{% dump %}` tag (requires `symfony/twig-bridge` installed)

*Note: It's a twig-tag and **not a function** so no `()` needed!*

```
<body>
{% dump some_variable, 'data as string', ['hello', 'world'] %}
</body>
```

It behaves same as `dump($data);` in your controllers. It **moves** output to a debug-bar, so your layout stays untouched.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Can I capture or inject the output of the dump myself? I would like to implement a debug output in twig templates for those who don't have a profiler (e.g. on test environments) like so {% if env = dev%} {{dump (var)}}. But that leads to an error on production because the debug bundle is not loaded there. Now look for another way to do that than reimplementing dump ()

Comment: You could enable debug bundle for `dev` and `test` environment.
And then change your condition to `{% if env is not same as('prod') %} {{dump (var)}} {% endif %}`

Comment: That is exactly the way I did it, but this throws an error on production: dump() is parsed by the twig-parser in *any* case, not only if the condition fits. The above code snippet leads to an "unknown function" exception on prod.